# How to get unique Relation between 2 columns after Self Join Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, unique, networkx, relation

```
import pandas as pd

data={'x':['A','A','B','B','C','E','F'],
      'y':['B','C','A','C','D','F','G']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

I have a big dataframe like this one (simplified with ABC):

```
     x    y
0    A    B
1    A    C
2    B    A
3    B    C
4    C    D
5    E    F
6    F    G
```

There are "loops" like row 0: A <-> B and row 2: B <-> A which mean the same relation for me.

I want to have the relation between the x and y column values and give them a unique new id.

So for this example table this means:

A = B = C = D         give this a unique id, i.e. 90
E = F = G             give this a unique id, i.e. 91

The Result table i need should be:

```
    id  value
0   90    A
1   90    B
2   90    C 
3   90    D
4   91    E
5   91    F
6   91    G
```

How can i achieve this with pandas?
Help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Where does the 90 and 91 come from?

Comment: This is a random unique number which should be created. Does not need to be 90 or 91, i just wanted to clarify how the result should be grouped.

Comment: There is no D->A. How come A=B=C=D ?

Comment: Transitive Relation, 
row 1: A->C,
row 4: C->D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems like a graph, ie [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/) library, problem. Let's look for nodes in connected components within a graph network [(see this wiki page)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)).

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

data={'x':['A','A','B','B','C','E','F'],
      'y':['B','C','A','C','D','F','G']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'x','y')
g = nx.connected_components(G)
S = pd.Series()
for i,n in enumerate(g):
    s = pd.Series(sorted(list(n)), index=[i]*len(n))
    S = pd.concat([S, s])

S
```

Output:

```
0    A
0    B
0    C
0    D
1    E
1    F
1    G
dtype: object
```

Comment: This looks brilliant! Gonna test it tomorrow with the real data. I let you know if it worked out. Thank you very much!

Comment: Indeed brilliant, nice catch using graphs

Comment: It worked fine. Just added some lines to get it into a Dataframe in the format i want and the index into a seperate column:

    `result = pd.DataFrame(S)`
    `result = result.rename(columns={0:'Other_ID'})`
    `result['New_ID'] = S.index`
    
~Cheers

Comment: One more thing, the theory behind this is a breadth-first-search:
[connected component graph theory wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory))

Comment: @steff9488 Awesome. Good find on that wiki page.  I'll add to the text of this problem.  Happy coding!